# CSS trick to avoid overflow in using positioning properties

Tags: css

This issue happens in my custom swipable list element.
[image]
The logs written while scrolling are the `scrollLeft` of the list.

As I'm implementing a scroll element and its scrollbars, and a list element from the scratch, all elements' `overflow` is `hidden`. The list is flex box, and a child of it gets swiped by changing their `left` or `translateX` property(in the above demo, I just used `translateX` but both + changing `right` produce the same result). And changing the `left` property of the children causes this overflow.

I've already found solutions to avoid just the weird horizontal scrolling when there's a swiped child to the right(**note that the overflow of the list on y axis only happens when the `left` property is positive**), but they need more codes and some of them causes another issue like event handling in the DOM tree. So I want to find a nice and light trick solving this overflow.

Note that setting the `position` property of the children as `absolute` doesn't work.

To demonstrate this overflow occurrence, I made a backbone demo showing that setting a positive value on `left` property causes the overflow(see the horizontal scrollbar appears).

```css
* {
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
}
body {
  height: 90vh;
}
#view-scroller {
  display: flex;
}
#swipable-list-view {
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: flex;
}
[swiped] {
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="view-scroller">
  <div id="swipable-list-view">
    <div>Item</div>
    <div swiped>Swiped Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: If this is a list, why not use the correct semantics `<ul><li>…</li></ul>`. I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve here. Could you elaborate more on the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @ShannonYoung Sorry if it was ambiguous, I added the requested more explanation, but I just hadn't put it in the text from the first as I think it isn't really needed for this question. So the conclusion is that they are actually custom-tags not div or any built-in tags. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: hidden` on `#swipable-list-view` stops anything with the attribute `[swiped]` from overflowing its container.

I would also suggest using [css-transforms](/questions/tagged/css-transforms) to move the `[swiped]` element, as this is [better for animation transitions](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108).

```
[swiped] {
    transform: translateX(20%);
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't put that there's a normalizing selector which sets `overflow: hidden` on all elements. It just hides the overflowed area, so `scrollWidth` becomes larger than the width. I need a trick that makes the box not cause overflow at all, but it seems there's no way to do that. I'm gonna implement what I want just by a same copy with absolute position. By the way thank you for letting me know the smooth animation method :)